# Дискретизация значений в SQL-бд

Tags: sql

По требованиям проекта потребовалось записывать несколько простых потоков TS-данных в БД. Предполагается запись данных в простую табличку:

```
type        | id         | taken_at            | value
click_count | region:spb | 2016-01-01 10:00:00 | 12
view_count  | *          | 2016-01-01 10:00:02 | {"anonymous": 12, "logged": 3}
```

Естественно, нам нужно генерировать отчеты по этой таблицы, в том числе с дискретизацией: пользователь может указать, что ему нужны значения с определенным интервалом, например, в один день, тридцать минут или два часа, то есть, организовать следующую выборку на псевдокоде:

```
results = ts.query()
pointer = 0
filtered = []
last_date = 0
interval = 3600 // 1 час
while results.length < pointer:
  if last_date + interval < results[pointer].taken_at:
    filtered[] = results[pointer]
    last_date = results[pointer].taken_at
  pointer++
return filtered
```

Есть ли возможность организовать подобные выборки (включить строку в выборку; пропускать строки, пока они находятся в интервале даты предыдущего значения + указанный пользователем интервал; повторять, пока остаются записи) на уровне SQL? Конкретный движок, если это важно - MySQL,  в идеале, конечно, хотелось бы найти решение, не зависящее от движка.

Comment: А как по-русски будет "сэмплинг"?

Comment: Ну тут полюбому полным перебором хотя бы интервала идти, так что вполне можно привести дату к unix_time, т.е. числу секунд и брать записи с конкретными остатками от деления на 3600 например

Comment: Если остаток не устраивает, то от движка точно будет зависеть. MySQL как раз будет выделяться. в нем нет оконных функций и CTE, зато есть переменные, с помошью которых можно по произвольной логике пометить строки а во внешнем запросе отфильтровать. В других БД возможно помог бы рекурсивный CTE

Comment: @edem я затрудняюсь корректно перевести (иначе бы сразу написал). Я имею в виду взятие отдельных значений из общего потока по определенным условиям (в данном случае, по интервалу). --- disregard this, перевел!

Comment: @Mike на остаток не хотелось бы полагаться, потому что я не могу гарантировать временную точность, и некоторые отсчеты при этом могут пропадать. Можно расшифровать CTE? В гугле только медицинский термин.

Comment: @Etki common table expression. Интересует его рекурсивный вариант. Первая часть должна выбрать первую запись, вторая часть должна искать последующую. фактически вот этот цикл и получается. И кстати никто не мешает например округлить до часа или нужной величины и брать одну запись из округленного диапазона тем же самым остатком от деления или оконными функциями пронумеровать и взять N-ные номера

Comment: @Mike ага, понял

Answer (score 2):

Решили с использованием предложения от @Mike и некоторых статей, найденных через гугл - мы сделали round-robin хранение, вместо чего, конечно, стоило использовать сразу обычную RRD, но мы ограничены в выборе хранилища.

Каждая метрика в задаче характеризуется четырьмя параметрами:

- Тип (совокупность метрик одинаковой структуры, создаваемых из выборок с различной фильтрацией)
- Идентификатор (внутри типа)
- Срок хранения данных метрики (переводимый в секунды)
- Интервал, с которым должны браться значения метрики (аналогично переводимый в секунды)

Поделив срок хранения (range) на интервал (далее interval) можно определить, сколько метрик будет сохранено внутри одного range. Затем, используя простую математику с временными метками, можно поделить всю временную шкалу на отдельные отрезки, соответствующие интервалам:

```
range = 86400
timestamp | range #
0         | 0
86400     | 1
172800    | 2
...
```

Время внутри такого окна вычисляется обычным mod

```
range_timestamp = timestamp() % range
```

После этого в каждом range можно определить порядковый номер замера:

```
sample_sequence_number = round(range_timestamp / interval)
```

После чего вычисленный порядковый номер добавляется в первичный ключ и позволяет хранить ограниченное (range / interval) количество записей без необходимости строить сборщик мусора.

Таблица приобрела следующий вид:

```
type        | id         | sequence_number | taken_at            | value
click_count | region:spb | 0               | 2016-01-01 10:03:00 | 12
click_count | region:spb | 1               | 2016-01-01 10:01:00 | 5
click_count | region:spb | 2               | 2016-01-01 10:02:00 | 3
```

Кроме приятного бонуса с избавлением от сборки мусора эта схема позволяет легко выполнять вышеописанные выборки с округленным до кратного interval периодом. Например, если метрика снимается раз в пять минут, а пользователь запросил разрешение в 27 минут, движок сделает следующие операции:

- Округлит разрешение до ближайшего целого числа interval (`sampling = max(1, round(input / interval))`)
- Выполнит следующий запрос:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM statistics
  WHERE
    type = 'click_count' AND
    id = 'region:spb' AND
    sequence_number % sampling = 0 AND
    taken_at >= '2016-01-01 10:00' AND
    taken_at <= '2016-01-01 12:00'
  ORDER BY taken_at ASC
  ```

Опционально можно подкорректировать sampling с учетом текущей даты, но в нашей ситуации это необязательно.